# GNU Make on Windows Variable Evaluation

Tags: makefile

I am using version 3.18 of GNU make on Windows. I am trying to get this to work: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-auto-incrementing-build-number-your-build-process.

Here is a short version of the make file:

```
BUILD_NUMBER_FILE = buildnum.txt
BUILD_NUMBER_LDFLAGS = -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_DATE=$$(date +'%Y%m%d')
BUILD_NUMBER_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_NUMBER=$$(cat $(BUILD_NUMBER_FILE))

test:
  gcc -o test $(BUILD_NUMBER_LDFLAGS) test.cpp
```

On Linux this works perfectly, but on Windows the variable `BUILD_NUMBER_LDFLAGS` is not expanded to its teal value. I suspect this has something to do with make's interaction with the shell, but I'm not certain. I have tried setting the `SHELL` variable to point to the GNU sh, but it does not fix the problem.

Anyone know how to make this work??

Comment: What *is* it expanded to? What commands are actually being run? What is happening?

Comment: Here is the output from make:

D:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -o test -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_DATE=$(date +'%Y%m%d') -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_NUMBER=$(cat buildnum.txt) test.cpp
/bin/sh: D:mingwbingcc.exe: command not found
make: *** [test] Error 127

Maybe the expansion is happening, but make is removing backslashes when executing gcc. Wierd.

Comment: OK, my analysis was incorrect. Looks like the variable is being expanded correctly. See below. I run echo.exe and can see it is working. The *real* problem is that when there is a variable like this that is expanded then the full path to the tool (echo, gcc, etc.) is wrong in that the backslashes are removed. There seems to be a workaround of quoting the path. I guess make on Windows just handles paths way different, but this really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Run `echo foo\bar\baz` at your shell prompt. See what you get? That's the shell un-escaping the string. That's how the shell works. So, yes, you need to quote the arguments or double the backslashes... or just use forward slashes instead. But that snippet of makefile shouldn't have generated that output. Does you real makefile use `$(CC)` or something instead of `gcc`? (Or is your `test` target not actually being run?)

Comment: Thanks. I converted everything to use forward slashes and make is much happier. The implementation is inconsistent though. You cannot use forward slashes for VPATH on Windows. If you do it is as if the VPATH is never set, while use backslashes for VPATH works. It would be best of the Windows implementation honored backslashes for everything as that is what the underlying OS uses.

Comment: There is no "3.18" version of make.  Presumably you mean 3.81.  That version is almost 10 years old now.  I've never heard of anyone ever having any problems using forward slashes in VPATH, so I'm sceptical that this is a problem.  But perhaps a newer version of GNU make would help.